# How to create a stored procedure with dynamic from clause

Tags: sql-server

I have a problem with an application which uses the same stored procedure over and over again to populate people information in dropdown lists. The problem is that sometimes people aren't there anymore as the data changes. I have two views I can use to select from, but I want to dynamically change which view is being used based on the state of the application.

For new records, I only want to see current people. If I'm updating an existing record, I may want to see all people since the existing record may reference someone who is not current anymore.

How would I go about passing the view name in to my stored procedure so I can select from it?

I've already tried adding:

```
@view varchar(50)

select a, b from @view
```

But I get an error stating I must declare the variable @view.

Is this even possible to do?

Comment: Be very careful, a hacker could pass "people; drop table people;" to destroy/hack/takeover your database.

Comment: This won't happen. The @view will get set in some .net code and is not accessible by user input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use only two views and you know their names, you could just pass a bit parameter to a procedure.

```
@useFirstView bit

IF @useFirstView = 1 
   -- select from firstView
ELSE
   -- select from secondView
```

Comment: Using this method can help you avoid using dynamic SQL.  Dynamic SQL can lead to SQL injection attacks.  This may or may not be an issue for you.

Comment: I used this principal and it's working. Even though there is code duplication, this is the quickest / simplest fix and is easy enough to understand.

Thank-you for your response!

Answer (score 2):

You can create your statement in the SP and call:

```
exec sp_executesql @sql
```

Comment: You can also paramaterize the SQL to help avoid injection attacks.

Comment: He's doing that, wrote it in its question. But his problem is the parametrization of the SP.

Comment: He is passing parameters into the SP yes but if he created some dynamic SQL and executed it using sp_executesql he will probably conver the param to a string and pass it into sp_executesql blindly. When you can also parameterize the dynamic SQL as well, meaning it is a lot safer i.e. sql injection

Answer (score 1):

I was wondering about the exact same thing and I came across this thread in the MSDN forums:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/transactsql/thread/fa523f21-5a8b-421f-99ce-9bb2ec30e848

Take a look at the answer of Sami Samir in the end - at least for me it provided a perfect solution and I hope it will do the same for you.

Dynamic SQL for a dynamic choice between a fixed number of tables/views which have the same fields just doesn't sound right - hard to debug and error/hack attack-prone.

All the best.

Answer (score 0):

You can use dynamic SQL to solve your issue.

```
DECLARE @sqlCommand varchar(1000)
SET @sqlCommand = 'SELECT a, b from FROM ' + @view
EXEC (@sqlCommand)
```

But I don't think that this is the best solution. You should probably have a query like

```
If @IsActiveFlag = TRUE THEN
  SELECT * FROM People WHERE IsActive = 1
ELSE
  SELECT * FROM People
ENDIF
```

Comment: correct, but it sounds, to me, as though he's asking the wrong question. Sure he can select from different views, but perhaps he can simplify his life by not requiring two views and instead get away with one view and a where clause.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried declaring a variable within the stored procedure and assigning the parameter as it's value?

For example, assuming you have a parameter named @view:

> declare @viewName nvarchar(50)
>
> set @viewName = @view

Comment: Yes I tried this and it's not working for me. It produces 3 errors instead of just 1.

Comment: Sure it provides more errors, @view must be declared and set like @viewName here.

Answer (score -1):

You just miss the declaration of you variable

```
DECLARE @view VARCHAR(50)
SET @view = 'myView'
SELECT a,b FROM @view
```

or if used in an stored procedure

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SelectFromView
{
    @view VARCHAR(50)
}
AS
BEGIN

    DECLARE @sqlCommand varchar(1000)
    SET @sqlCommand = 'SELECT a, b from FROM ' + @view
    EXEC (@sqlCommand)

END
```

Beware of SQLInjection attacs on this, like mentioned before.

[edit]
Corrected use of dynamic sql creation with the code from Nathan Koop, thx.
[/edit]

Answer (score -1):

Your idea is tempting, but this is NOT SUPPORTED (why do people here even suggest to DECLARE a variable?) or, in other words, you're doing it the wrong way.

The FROM clause accepts either a table/view/function name (hardcoded, not from a varchar variable) or a table variable. 
A table variable looks like this:

```
DECLARE @table TABLE (a int, b int).
```

Note that it is of type TABLE, not VARCHAR. After that you can do:

```
SELECT a,b FROM @table.
```

But obviously this is not what you want. I would suggest to use sp_executesql (only if view/table names are set by you, not coming from user data or similar) or an IF-ELSE statement.